# vertical line between div element and it's own border in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I specified a div element with a bottom border, using the same color as the div itself, to create a vertically asymmetric placement of the background image. However a very fine line appears between the div and its border (the element and its border have the color #141414, the 1px wide line is #2c2c2c).

The Chrome developer tools say the line doesn't exist, but is visible anyway. The problem does not exist in Firefox or Internet Explorer and only appears with some window widths, not with others, but in varying brightnesses.

It only appears when I use padding-box on the background.

html

```
<div id="titleBlock">Title Text</div>
```

css

```
#titleBlock {
    background: url("logo2.svg") center center no-repeat #141414 padding-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 9.25vw;
    text-align: center;
    color: #DCDCDC;
    font-size: 3.3vw;
    padding-top: 20.75vw;
    font-weight: 300;
    border-bottom: #141414 solid 3vw;
}
```

Has anyone else experienced this or knows a solution without creating a second div to represent the bottom border?

Comment: Since I'm having the same result on both Firefox and Chrome with your code, try to remove the background-image and see if doesn't come from it.

Comment: I have tried that, removing the image doesn't help

Comment: Worth noting that `padding-box` is not standard: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Could you post a working example on Codepen to show you bug?

Comment: @bluemoon6790 What you're saying is not correct. In the OP's code, `padding-box` is a value of the [`background-clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip) property. You link to the page for the `border-box` property.

Comment: @MrLister You're completely right. I had never seen that used before! Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

How important is that extra 0.25% of view width to you?

I got it to disappear in Chrome by bumping the `padding top: 20.75vw` to `padding-top: 21vw`.

Comment: That's a good point, I should have realised something like that should solve it

Comment: However on smaller screen sizes the problem persists, pretty much whenever there is a fraction involved in the height of the div or the width of the border